# Vercel не отправляет MP3, MP4 файлы (Python Flask)

Tags: python, flask

Пытаюсь отправлять MP3 файл с помощью Flask на web хостинге "Vercel"
Но я получаю "500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR", логи с этой ошибки не приходят...
Запускал на локалке все работает.
Сам код Flask:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def wtmusicindex():
    return {
        "message": "This is WhatTheMusic api"
    }

@app.route('/music')
async def wtmusicmusicroute():
    return {
        "message": "This is music route"
    }, 200

@app.route('/music/get/<music>')
async def wtmusicsendmusic(music):
    try:
        return send_file(f'musics/{music}')
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            "ERRROR": f"{e}"
        }, 500

@app.route('/music/info')
async def wtmusicinfomusic():
    return {
        "message": "coming soon"
    }, 200

@app.route('/music/random/') #coming soon
async def musicrandom(id=1):
    return {
        "Name": "Never Too Far",
        "by": "Sorrow",
        "link": "https://api-wtmusic.vercel.app/music/get/Sorrow-NeverTooFar.mp3"
    }, 200
```

Прошу ответить на вопрос, почему Vercel не отправляет MP3, MP4 файлы?

(P.S. можете сами [посмотреть](https://api-wtmusic.vercel.app/music/get/Sorrow-NeverTooFar.mp3))